# how to delete a node reference type in drupal 6

Tags: drupal

I have successfully deleted the node from the database (i checked it) but the problem is the nid wont dissapear in the node reference field. how do i delete this? here's my code which dosnt work

```
if($op == 'delete' && $node->type == 'person'){


    $id = $node->nid;



    $q=db_query("select nid from content_field_movie_cast where field_movie_cast_nid = '$id'"); //get all the movie ids that have the cast
    db_query("DELETE from content_field_movie_cast where field_movie_cast_nid = '$id' "); // delete all the entry for that cast in a all the movies it is involve

    while($result=db_fetch_array($q)){

    $node1=node_load($result['nid']);

                $ctr=0;
                $cnt=count($node1->field_movie_cast);

                while($ctr<$cnt){

                        if($node1->field_movie_cast[$ctr]['nid']==$id){

                        dpm($node1->field_movie_cast[$ctr]['nid']=0);

                        node_delete($nid);

                        }

                $ctr++;
                }


    db_query("update content_type_movie set field_movie_cast_count_value =field_movie_cast_count_value -1 where nid = '".$result['nid']."' ");


    }
    }
```

here's a picture too of what im talking about the nid without a name is the one i want to delete

[image]

Comment: From your last couple of questions it sounds like you're looking for [Referential Integrity for CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck_referential_integrity)...my understanding is that will replace the need for your custom code, and it looks to be stable with 0 open bugs

Comment: Dunno I've never used it, but it was built for exactly your purpose. Install it on your dev site and see...

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I used node_ref. and D6, though I'm a bit confused about your approach. You deleted the node from the db? Meaning you deleted the node from the UI or by using http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_delete/6, not by doing strange stuff directly in the database?

Nodes refereeing to this node will still have the A -> B reference stored. If you edit the node does it allow you to save it, normally will it req. you to remove the non existing ref. ID before saving/previewing.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I think the approach is a bit strange, I will take the following programmatic approach:

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    //dsm($form);
    unset($form['field_movie_cast']['und'][0]['nid']['#default_value']);
}
```

This is based on D7 so for D6 there maybe need for slight adjustments to the code.